# using module '\\UNC\Share\folder\file.psm1' creates a "Preparing modules for first use" progress bar that doesn't vanish

Tags: powershell

I have a module located in a server at: `\\UNCpath\Share\Scripts\Modules\Test\Test.psm1`

I'm trying the following:

```
using module `\\UNCpath\Share\Scripts\Modules\Test\Test.psm1`

ModuleFunction -Parameter1 'example' -Switch1   # Function that takes some time and
                                                # prints a lot of stuff on the screen

Write-Host 'Done.'
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
```

When I start the script in the Terminal, a progress bar appears "**Preparing modules for first use.**", and it doesn't go away until the script finishes.

**How can I get rid of it?**

Here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

###### $PSVersionTable

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.22621.963
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.22621.963
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```